# What is this syntax in java `<E> Sets.SetView<E>`?

Tags: java

Here is some code that I was trying to understand

```
public static <E> Sets.SetView<E> difference(final Set<E> set1, final Set<?> set2) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(set1, "set1");
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(set2, "set2");
    final Predicate<Object> notInSet2 = Predicates.not(Predicates.in(set2));
    return new Sets.SetView<E>() {
        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
            return Iterators.filter(set1.iterator(), notInSet2);
        }

        public int size() {
            return Iterators.size(this.iterator());
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return set2.containsAll(set1);
        }

        public boolean contains(Object element) {
            return set1.contains(element) && !set2.contains(element);
        }
    };
}
```

I am confuse on what the function is returning, when I use it, it would seems like the function is returning `Sets.SetView<E>`

For example

```
        Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Integer> b = new HashSet<>();
        a.add(1);
        Sets.difference(a, b); // is of type Sets.SetView<Long>
```

What is the extra `<E>` prepend in front?

And why does the actual return value contains method definition?

```
    return new Sets.SetView<E>() {
        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
            return Iterators.filter(set1.iterator(), notInSet2);
        }

        public int size() {
            return Iterators.size(this.iterator());
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return set2.containsAll(set1);
        }

        public boolean contains(Object element) {
            return set1.contains(element) && !set2.contains(element);
        }
    };
```

Comment: It's a generic method.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: When you pass it a set of Integer, for example, it returns a `SetView<Integer>`.  That's all it means.  The type of set you pass it is the type of SetView it returns.

Comment: `why does the actual return value contains method definition` That's an anonymous class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html  You really need to study up on Java syntax.

Comment: The "extra" `<E>` in front is the type parameter declaration. A type parameter must be declared before it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Don't read as `<E> Sets.SetView<E>`.  The method returns `Sets.SetView<E>`.   the prepend `<E>` is the generic template syntax on static method.